# Mask Email in JSON String Using regex

Tags: java, json, regex, string

I have an email masking regex and now I am trying to apply it on JSON Strings for masking email.

```
Regex: (?<=.{1})(?=[a-zA-Z0-9]).(?=.*@)
```

It works fine if we apply it on email in String variable.

```
String s = "test.ing%02@gmail.com";                        
s= s.replaceAll("(?<=.{1})(?=[a-zA-Z0-9]).(?=.*@)", "*");
```

**Output:** `t***.***%**@gmail.com`

Now I am trying to apply it on JSON String which contains the email field. I selected the email field but regex is not identifying its value

```
String jsonString = "{ \"name\":\"jhon\", \"email\":\"test.ing%02@gmail.com\" }";                                        
String result = jsonString.replaceAll("(?<=email\":\")((?<=.{1})(?=[a-zA-Z0-9]).(?=.*@))(?=\")", "*");                    
System.out.println(result);
```

**Actual Output:** `{ "name":"jhon", "email":"test.ing%02@gmail.com" }`

**Expected Output:** `{ "name":"jhon", "email":"t***.***%**@gmail.com" }`

Answer (score 2):

You might update the pattern to making use of a finite lookbehind assertion:

```
(?<=email":"[^\s"]{1,100})[a-zA-Z0-9](?=[^\s"@]*@)
```

The pattern in parts:

- `(?<=email":"` Positive lookbehind, assert `email":"` to the left

  - `[^\s"]{1,100}` Match 1-100 times a non whitespace char other than `"` to the left (adjust the quantifier as needed)
- `)` Close the lookbehind
- `[a-zA-Z0-9]` Match a single char a-zA-Z0-9
- `(?=[^\s"@]*@)` Positive lookahead, assert a `@` to the right without crossing double quotes

See a [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/80B1rp/1) and a [Java demo](https://ideone.com/7I2RTr).

Example in Java with the doubled backslashes and escaped double quotes:

```
String jsonString = "{ \"name\":\"jhon\", \"email\":\"test.ing%02@gmail.com\" }";
String result = jsonString.replaceAll("(?<=email\":\"[^\\s\"]{1,100})[a-zA-Z0-9](?=[^\\s\"@]*@)", "*");
System.out.println(result);
```

Output

```
{ "name":"jhon", "email":"t***.***%**@gmail.com" }
```

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash Yeah I missed the first character, but I think that you might also exclude the double quote right?

Comment: Excellent! Now, it meets the requirement precisely.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash I think you had a good point writing it like this `(?<=email\":\"[^\s\"]{1,100})[a-zA-Z0-9](?=[^\s\"@]*@)` as the first assertion already makes sure that there is no `"` to the left. I have updated it.